# Save data locally and sync back to central db server

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, sqlite

I have a python program which gathers a set of data every 10 secs. It needs to run on various computers at the same point of time. **What is the best way to send all data to a central DB server?** Data collected when computer is not connected with the internet must also be sent to the central DB server.

Comment: Let the tags speak to what solutions you're employing or asking for. Don't put that in the title, it just clutters things up.

Comment: Define "set of data"? How much? How long does it take to transfer this data?

Comment: @tadman: I will use the tags better from next time.                                        Set of Data: 10 columns with TEXT. Primarily a timestamp, hostname, public ip, private ip, active window tile name, URL (if browser), and system uptime... there might be 2 - 3 more columns but similar type (text data). Thanks in advance.

Comment: A `SHOW CREATE TABLE` helps here, you can edit your question to include that information if you think it's relevant. It really sounds like you just need a queue that can forward data from one server to another, maybe even something like [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com) where one instance is configured to send to another so long as they're connected.

Comment: Are you looking for this?
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE Process_ (hostname TEXT, loIP TEXT, puIP TEXT, time TEXT, uptime TEXT,tile TEXT, url TEXT)''')

Comment: I dont think I can edit the question now. OK. I can use VARCHAR (50) - but when I run this program and if internet is connected it sends the data to my hosted mysql server. What do I need to do to store data locally when internet is not available and when internet is available it should send all the stored data??

Comment: There's a lot of engineering you have to do here. SQLite might be a good thing to use locally and buffer, but the sync problem is not trivial. You'll need to plan ahead to figure out how to replicate that data, and that's way more than what can be answered in a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It has really helped me a lot - it was a great solution!!!

Comment: This has been solved. If anyone wants the code please email me at joyd86@gmail.com

Comment: It's generally best to post whatever solution you came up with here. Advertising your email is not the way to do it.

Comment: Hello TADMAN, I have been able to arrive to the soln. only because of your valued suggestion - would like to use this platform to show my gratitude for your help and expertise :) AND why dont you let me use this platform the way I feel is best!???

Comment: You're welcome, but do keep in mind this site has rules and if people treat those as optional it will quickly degrade into chaos. You're not alone here, you're part of a community, and that community would like to see whatever solution you've come up with rather than have to email you and wait. This could affect someone years in the future when that address is no longer active, questions here can last for a long time.